# Area of overlap of two circles

Tags: geometry, circles, recreational-mathematics, area

A line segment $\overline{AB}$ has a length of $x$. A circle with center $A$ has a radius of $r_1$, and another circle with center $B$ has a radius of $r_2$. Also, $r_1+r_2>x$ and $x,r_1,r_2>0$ and $r_1,r_2<x$. Is it possible to find the area of the region inside both circles? If so, how?

(example graph of problem(Desmos))

[image]

[Link to the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gm5g5ryfdr)

(I don't know if this is a duplicate or not; I will delete this question if it is a duplicate)

Comment: I'm not too sure how to approach this problem because I am only in the eighth grade, but I think to connect $A$ and $B$ to the two points where the two circles meet.

Comment: It is definitely possible. If you know calculus, this resumes to calculating an (many) integral(s)  (the hard part may be finding the limits of integration).

Comment: Oh, so there's no other way to do it than calculus? :(

Comment: See the formula for [the area of an "asymmetric lens"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(geometry)#Special_cases) on Wikipedia. No calculus required, but you'll need some basic trig to find the angles involved.

Comment: Is there a proof for the formula shown in the wiki page? Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: The formula that says: $A=r^2\text {cos}^{-1}\left(\frac{d^2+r^2-R^2}{2dr}\right)+R^2\text{cos}^{-1}\left(\frac{d^2+R^2-r^2}{2dR}\right)-2\Delta$, 
where $\Delta = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(-d+r+R)(d-r+R)(d+r-R)(d+r+R)}$

Comment: @AidenChow: In a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ (with $a$ opposite $A$, etc), the Law of Cosines says that $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2a b\cos C \quad\to\quad C=\cos^{-1}\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$ So, the Wikipedia formula simply reads $$r^2\cdot(\angle\;\text{between $d$ and $r$})+R^2\cdot(\angle\;\text{between $d$ and $R$})-2\cdot(\text{area of}\;\triangle)$$ The first term gives twice the area of the circular sector subtended by the first angle; likewise, the second term. The last term subtracts-away the triangle area, leaving the area of two circular segments (ie, the lens).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $CE = h$ and note that $x=AB = AE + EB $, i.e.
$$x =\sqrt{r_2^2-h^2} + \sqrt{r_1^2-h^2}$$
Square to get
$x^2+r_2^2-r_1^2 = 2x\sqrt{r_2^2-h^2}$; square again to obtain

$$h=\frac1{2x}\sqrt{2x^2r_1^2+2x^2r_2^2+2r_1^2r_2^2-x^4-r_1^4-r_2^4}$$

Then, the circle sector angles are, respectively

$$\alpha = \sin^{-1}\frac h{r_1}, \>\>\>\>\>\beta= \sin^{-1}\frac h{r_2}$$

and the purple and orange areas are respectively the differences between the corresponding circle sectors and triangles, i.e.

$$S_a = \alpha r_1^2 - h\sqrt{r_1^2-h^2},\>\>\>\>\>
S_b = \beta r_2^2 - h\sqrt{r_2^2-h^2}$$

Thus, the area enclosed by the two circles is

$$Area=S_a+S_b =  r_1^2\sin^{-1}\frac h{r_1} + r_2^2 \sin^{-1}\frac h{r_2} - xh$$

where $h$ is given above.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-In the attached figure you can calculate the intersection point $P$ and the angles $a$ and $b$. You know the area of a circular sector $OPR$ is given by $\dfrac{r_1^2a}{2}$ where $a$ is in radians of course.

1) Area of triangle $OPO'$minus area of circular sector $O'PS$ = area of sector $OPS$

2)Requested area = 2($\dfrac{r_1^2a}{2}$ minus area of sector $OPS$)

[image]

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your solution, you're missing a factor of $1/2$ on sector OPR's area? (in first paragraph)

Comment: @David Peterson.-Yes. I had a lapse because I haven't seen this formula for a long time. Thank you.